# How has the interface changed from the Fuji X100 to the Fuji X100S?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, fujifilm, camera-controls

How does the Fuji X100 interface different from X100S?

I've read a lot of reviews that said that when the X100 first came out, the interface was very convoluted.   Also I read that with the latest firmware update, a lot of these issues were fixed but not sure how much.

Ideally I would like to make an informed decision if the menu update in the latest firmware version is worth getting an X100 over the X100S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full list of feature differences between the two cameras [can be found here](http://snapsort.com/compare/Fujifilm-FinePix-X100s-vs-Fujifilm_FinePix_X100/specs), and there's [a good general comparison of the two here](http://www.thevisualexperience.org/web/fujifilm-x100-vs-x100s/).

There is a detailed look at the menus on the X100S [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrmUyEy_C_k).

I hope that helps...

Mike